# Relationship of two time series using Scikit or Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, time-series

Say I have two hypothetical time series data one for rainfall and the other is ocean surface temperature.

```
Rainfall Time Series:
2001-12-31    25 mm
2002-12-31    50 mm
2003-12-31    75 mm
2004-12-31    50 mm
2005-12-31    25 mm
2006-12-31    10 mm
2007-12-31    6 mm
2008-12-31    8 mm
2009-12-31    10 mm
2010-12-31    12 mm
2011-12-31   20 mm
2012-12-31    75 mm

Rainfall Time Series:
2001-12-31   36 (Degrees Celsius)
2002-12-31   37 (Degrees Celsius)
2003-12-31   38 (Degrees Celsius)
2004-12-31   37 (Degrees Celsius)
2005-12-31   36 (Degrees Celsius)
2006-12-31   34 (Degrees Celsius)
2007-12-31   32 (Degrees Celsius)
2008-12-31   33 (Degrees Celsius)
2009-12-31   34 (Degrees Celsius)
2010-12-31   35 (Degrees Celsius)
2011-12-31   35.9 (Degrees Celsius)
2012-12-31    38 (Degrees Celsius)
```

I wanted to answer these questions:

```
1.) How are the two time series related?
2.) Is there a way to find out that if either one of time series changes the other one will also change? And if it does by how much?
```

We know that rainfall and ocean surface temperature are related and not spurious (unlike the time series example of Airline Passengers and Rice Production in https://goo.gl/EcR3sO)  I have read about Approximate Entropy and Regression of two time series, I even read that ARIMA is also a good way to to determine the relationship of two time series data yet I havent found any good detailed example in python using scikit or pandas. I prefer to use Entropy but I do not know if it can answer question 2. I would also like to ask if there is a permutation distribution clustering in python, this seems to be an interesting way to solve question 1. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please clarify which model you want to use. Otherwise the question is unclear or too broad.

Comment: @Goyo it would really help if you have ideas about permutation distribution clustering in python or if none, then entropy will be a good choice.

Answer (score 3):

Just plot them together in a scatterplot and you should be able to tell the relation:

1) How are the two series related? (example using UnivariateSpline, just use whatever you prefer)

```
    x = 25,50,75,50,25,10,6,8,10,12,20,75
    y = 36,37,38,37,36,34,32,33,34,35,35.9,38

    import numpy as np
    from scipy import interpolate
    f = interpolate.UnivariateSpline(x, y)
    xo = np.linspace(min(x),max(x),1000)
    yo = f(xo)

    df = np.diff(yo) / np.diff(xo)
    print(df.shape,xo.shape)
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.scatter(x,y)
    plt.plot(xo,yo)
    plt.show()
```

2) How does it change? Using the 1st derivative of the function "fitted" to data.

```
    plt.plot(xo[:-1],df)
    plt.show()
```